# Stata: Combine and Sort categories

Tags: stata

Is that possible to ask stata to combine variables and sort them out in order?

My data file is a list of inventories, look something similar to the picture posted below. I have in total of 7 categories that I assign to a specific characteristic. However, these categories are not in order. For example, one would have satin and damask and the next would be damask and satin. Is that possible to ask stata to combine variables and sort them out in order?

I want to have a final column that contains all 7 categories and in order. For instance, no matter if the previous column's order is satin and damask or damask and satin, it will all become satin and damask at the end. No matter if the previous columns write fox wool satin in whatever order, it became the same order at the last column. There are about 100s of different words in the first category and then less and less in the following.

Then I can convert this from long-form to short-form to form a person list instead of a list of inventories for further graphing and calculations.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qylpL.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please add more information so that we can help you. See here for guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info

Answer (score 0):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str6(cat1 cat2) str5 cat3
"satin"  "damask" ""     
"damask" "satin"  ""     
"wool"   "fox"    "satin"
"satin"  "fox"    "wool" 
end
```

Part of what you want may just be a combined table. Install `tab_chi` from SSC using `ssc install tab_chi` and then you have `tabm` installed: see its help for more.

```
. tabm cat?

           |                   values
  variable |    damask        fox      satin       wool |     Total
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
      cat1 |         1          0          2          1 |         4 
      cat2 |         1          2          1          0 |         4 
      cat3 |         0          0          1          1 |         2 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         2          2          4          2 |        10 

. tabm cat?, transpose

           |             variable
    values |      cat1       cat2       cat3 |     Total
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
    damask |         1          1          0 |         2 
       fox |         0          2          0 |         2 
     satin |         2          1          1 |         4 
      wool |         1          0          1 |         2 
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
     Total |         4          4          2 |        10
```

Note. What's with the foxes? Did foxes have to die so people could wear them?

Note. You may have to bite the bullet and `reshape long`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is an inventory of people's owning from the 16th century, thus you see foxes and wools and things like that. I will try your command! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1576264-question-on-combine-and-sort-variables